# How to pass the props to react functional component using react table and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to pass two arguments to react functional component using react table and typescript.

below is my code,

```
type NameCellValue = {
    name: string;
    type: string;
}

type NameCellProps = {
    value: NameCellValue;
    mode: Mode;
    canOpen: boolean;
}

const NameCell: React.FC<NameCellProps> = ({
    value: {name,type},
    mode,
    canOpen
}) => {
    console.log(mode) //this is undefined
    console.log(canOpen) //this is undefined
    canOpen: boolean,
}

const buildColumns : (
    mode: Mode,
    canOpen?: boolean
) => Column<Data>[] = (mode, canOpen) => [
    {
        Header: 'Name',
        id: 'name',
        accessor: ({name, type}) => ({
            name,
            type,
        }),
        Cell: NameCell(mode, canOpen), //how do i pass mode and canOpen to NameCell
    } as Column<Data, NameCellProps['value'] | NameCellProps['mode] | NameCellProps['canOpen']>,
    ];


const ParentComponent = () => {
    const columns = buildColumns(mode, canOpen);
    return (
        //some jsx
    );
}
```

the above doesnt work. it gives error "argument of type Mode is not assignable to parameter of type PropsWithChildren on line

```
Cell: NameCell(mode, canOpen)
```

also when i log the values of mode and canOpen within NameCell they are undefined.

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always render react components with angle bracket syntax, like:

```
<NameCell value={value} mode={myModeHere} canOpen />
```

It is possible to call the function directly, but you have to pass props as an object, like:

```
NameCell({ value, mode: myModeHere, canOpen: true })
```

But use the angle brackets as in the first example unless you have a *very* good reason.